# Click anywhere to go home?

Tags: jquery

I've googled but I cant seem to find any jquery that; when a user clicks anywhere it takes them to the index. For example, if a user is on a project but wants to go home they can click anywhere and it will take them home.

However, the same bit of jquery shouldn't be applied when a user is on the homepage?

The site I'm trying to implement it on is [here](http://www.speakingwithpictures.com) I tried implementing @jonathanchow answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var home = "http://www.speakingwithpictures.com";

$(body).click(
function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  if (window.location.href!=home)
  {
    window.location = home;
  }
});
</script>
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: Just don't include the script in the index page.

Comment: you should use `$('body')` instead of `$(body)` (otherwise `body` is interpreted as a variable

Comment: do you realise the www. version of your domain doesn't work? ;)

Comment: @giorgio just realised, amended the script. Tried your solution now the image doesnt click through to a bigger version. When a user is on a bigger version the jquery should kick in then.

Comment: you said _anywhere_, so I gave you the anywhere solution ;) Check out my updated answer for the almost anywhere solution :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive props to @giorgio.

However, the solution below answered my question. Please note tumblr's API was preventing @giorgio's from working:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "http://speakingwithpictures.com";
    });
</script>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've revised the code, [check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/KKY4T/2/). I believe this is what you need, or at least is very close to it, you should be able to tailor it to your needs.

To understand what is going on, first of all you need to understand how event bubbling (or propagation) works. We're using jQuery, so I'll only explain how jQuery handles it (it's almost the same as most browsers do btw).

When an event occurs on a certain element, the event handler is called for that particular event. But(!) the event also 'bubbles up' the DOM tree and executes all event handlers attached to the elements it finds on its way. Example [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zF8CM/):

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="in-the-middle">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div').on('click', function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr('class');
    });
</script>
```

Now, if you click on the middle div, the click event is called and you'll get an alert saying "in-the-middle". But the event bubbles up to the outer div, and finds a click event attached to that one too, so another alert saying "outer" will pop-up too. If you click the outer one, only "outer" will be shouted out, and when clicking the inner one, all three are alerted.

Now back to your problem. The problem with the code I gave before (in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKY4T/1/)) is that it did not took care well enough with this principle. Now take a look at the code in the new fiddle above and look at the following lines:

```
var target = $(e.target);
var find = target.parents('.do-not-go-to-home');

if(!target.hasClass('do-not-go-to-home') && find.length <= 0) {
    ...
}
```

In the first line you see `e.target`. The variable `e` is just the event, passed to the event handler. The target is the DOM element where the event first occurred, or which triggered the event. Now what I'm doing is traversing all the way up to the document itself (from the target to it's parent, to it's parent, and so on, passed the body to the document). When along the way an element with class '.do-not-go-to-gome' is found, it's stored in the find parameter.

Now in the if-clause you can check if along the way this class is found (find.length should be zero), or if the target itself had that class. Why? If you click some div with the class 'do-not-go-to-home' one of it's parents could be executing the event handler anyway. We've tackled that problem now.

Only thing to note is the little snipper `:not(.homepage)` in the selector. This will make sure the event is attached to every body element (of which there is only one) *that is NOT of the class `homepage`*. So on your homepage, make sure your body tag looks like this: `<body class="homepage">`. Other methods to discriminate the homepage from any other page are possible too ofcourse.

Have fun!

**Original answer**
Well, just attach the click event to the body. And add a class or do something else to determine if it's the homepage. DO something like:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('homepage')) {
        window.location.href = 'http://myhomepage.com';
    }
} );
```

**EDIT**
Aha! You're question just got a bit extended. So you want the user to click anywhere to go home, except for certain divs (eg. your images). In that case, just add a filter.

```
<div class="do-not-go-home">content</div>

$('body').on('click', 'div:not(.do-not-go-home)', function(){});
```

Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KKY4T/1/

Comment: still no luck. If you go to http://speakingwithpictures.com the jquery just forces the page to reload. What I'm looking to do is when somebody is on a post like http://speakingwithpictures.com/post/56865487613 it takes them home.

Comment: If you include the snippet from the fiddle on any page, it'll direct the user to the homepage (if you alter the url that is ;)). On the homepage itself you should add the homepage class to the body element, like so: `<body class="homepage">`. That makes sure the part that redirects is not executed. Or you could just only load the javascript on the post pages (and not the homepage). I can't find either the script or the body class on your site though...

Comment: sorry script is uploaded. Still when i try and click through to a post it just reloads the page. Do I need to need to change 'homepage' to anything?

Answer (score 2):

```
var home = "http://www.example.com/index";

$('body').click(
function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  if (window.location.href!=home)
  {
    window.location = home;
  }
});
```

Comment: should be `$('body')` (`body` is interpreted as a variable)

Comment: @Michael just added quotes around 'body'

Answer (score 0):

Something on these lines:

```
$('document').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).href != "homepage") {
        window.location = "homepage";
    }
});
```